# ObservableCollection doesn't get bound to ListBox in codebehind

Tags: wpf, binding, collections, listbox, observable

I would like to bind a list box to an observable collection in code behind. This is what I am using for the binding:

```
Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.Source = symTable;
substanceList.SetBinding(ListBox.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

`symTable` inherits from `ObservableCollection`, the Count property gets updated appropriatelly so I know I am adding elements correctly, but the list box isn't. I didn't know what to set the path to, since in XAML it is bound to the whole list.

Note: When adding individual items to the ListBox they get shown, so it is not a display issue. I also tried:

```
this.Resources.Add("symTable", symTable);
```

in the window constructor and then this:

but it says the resource cannot be resolved.

I also tried adding it as a resource in XAML but it didn't work again:
//in the window's resources.

```
<s:SymbolTable x:Key="symTable"/> 
...
<ListBox x:Name="substanceList" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource symTable}}"/>
```

and then in code behind:

symTable = (SymbolTable)this.FindResource("symTable");

Does anyone know any other way to do this in code behind or XAML, I think the `ElementName` refers to objects defined in code behind.

Here is part of the class definition for symTable:

```
public class SymbolTable : ObservableCollection<Substance>
{
    Dictionary<string, Substance> symbolTable;
    ...
    public Substance Insert(Substance s)
    {

        if (!symbolTable.ContainsKey(s.Name))
        {
            symbolTable.Add(s.Name, s);
            Items.Add(s);
        }

        return symbolTable[s.Name];
    }
```

**Note** alright so I just noticed the most weird thing, Items.Add wasn't raising the INotifyChanged event. I used Items.Add in my Insert method, I am guessing that Items.Add doesn't raise a INotifyChanged event so the ListBox wasn't getting updated, but when did Add instead of Items.Add then it worked. Do you know if this is indeed the case?

Comment: I tried your code with an ObservableCollection<string> and that works pretty well. Maybe your items won't somehow be displayed in the ListBox. Check if your DataTemplate binds properly to your data object's properties, or post more of your code.

Comment: @Clemens when I set the ItemsSouce directly to symTable the items get displayed, adding individual items also works. I also tried `<ListBox x:Name="substanceList" ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=symTable, Path=Items}"` but it didn't work.

Comment: This can't work for two reason: symTable is (i guess) declared in code behind, so there is no XAML element named symTable, which makes the ElementName assignment useless. Moreover it has no Items property, which makes the Path assignment useless. You might declare your ObservableCollection as resource with x:Key=symTable and then bind `ItemsSource={Binding Source={StaticResource symTable}}`.

Comment: @Clemens how can I use symTable in code behind then to add items to it? This somehow looks like a workaround, isn't there a simplier way?

Comment: @Clemens I also tried adding it to a resource dictionary in the constructor, I updated the question above, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Oh, please drop that dictionary stuff in class SymbolTable, its completely wrong. When i say declare as resource i do of course mean in XAML. I'll add aanother answer for posting sample code.

Comment: @Clemens I did that too, for the above I meant in the window constructor not the SymbolTable constructor. I updated the question above for the xaml resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, following the comments on your question, here is how to declare SymbolTable as resource in XAML and how to bind a ListBox to it. Note the XAML namespace declaration 'local', which refers to the local namespace/assembly, which is named `ListBindingTest` in my test project.

```
<Window x:Class="ListBindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ListBindingTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:SymbolTable x:Key="symTable"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource symTable}}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

You may access the SymbolTable resource in code behind in your window class like this:

```
SymbolTable st = (SymbolTable)Resources["symTable"];
st.Add(new Substance());
```

Comment: alright so I just noticed the most weird thing, Items.Add wasn't raising the INotifyChanged event. I used Items.Add in my Insert method, I am guessing that Items.Add doesn't raise a INotifyChanged event so the ListBox wasn't getting updated, but when did Add instead of Items.Add then it worked. Do you know if this is indeed the case?

Comment: Ah, that's what i was just looking after also. Just must use `this.Add()` in your `Insert()` method.

Answer (score 0):

The DisplayMemberPath needs to be a public property of symTable.

Comment: @mihajlv In C#, when you have an [indexed accessor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664459%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the compiler creates an Items property for you, so that the property is accessible from other languages.

Comment: @Bevan I am not sure what you are refering to. The indexed accesor is from the private dictionary variable.

Comment: I thought you were confused why an Items property is present without being explicitly declared. Perhaps I misunderstood myself ...

Answer (score 0):

You could always just set the ItemSource directly on the listbox.

```
substanceList.ItemsSource = symTable;
```

Comment: but when the collection changes the listbox doesn't get updated.